# What is the most secure way to allow users to execute BCP export command from SQL?

Tags: sql-server, security, bcp, xp-cmdshell, sql-server-administration

I am currently working in an environment where the ability to **export** a table **programatically** from within a hand-run SQL script would be of great help.

Performing the exports from script will be the first step towards running the entire process from within a stored procedure, therefore I have to be able to initiate the export from SQL.

The organisation currently has the following configuration on most servers -

- SQL Server 2005 or 2008
- xp_cmdshell - **disabled**
- CLR - **enabled**

Ultimately, I would like to be able to call a procedure passing the following parameters and have it perform the export.

- table name
- file path/name (on a network share)
- file format

Currently BCP seems like a perfect option in terms of functionality but I am unable to invoke it via the command line due to xp_cmdshell being disabled.

The organisation is quite small and happy work towards a secure solution and my impression so far is that they have a good level of control over their security.  They have made a blanket decision to disable xp_cmdshell but if I could present a safe way to allow use of it I think they would be pretty receptive.

In my research I've come across both the **'EXECUTE AS'** functionality as well as signing procedures with **certificates**, but still cant work out if either approach can help me achieve what I want.

Also, if you have another solution that allows me to achieve the same end-result I'm all ears!

Comment: Why not have an app do this for you (you don't necessarily need BCP - a C# command-line app would be simple enough to write) - then all you have to do is give the users permissions to grab files from the folder where the app dumps the files. Or it could even e-mail them or put them in a network location the user already has access to.

Comment: How would I invoke the app? command line? Also, Being able to place the exported tables in a specific location is an essential part of the process as I am automating a manual process.  The files could need to be placed anywhere under a certain folder on one of 2 network shares.

Comment: Wouldn't I have the same problem calling a C# command-line app as I currently have trying to call BCP?

Comment: You could invoke the app from just about anywhere - a web page, a caller app, etc.

Comment: No, the problem you're encountering calling BCP is that you're doing it from within SQL Server and xp_cmdshell is disabled. A novel idea: have an app that calls BCP (or just dumps a SELECT from a table to a file) without going through T-SQL.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I've edited my question to try and make my requirements clearer.  I'm attempting to automate a process, end-to-end, if I have to stop and kick-off an external app manually then I wont have gained much in this scenario.  I think they would consider enabling xp_cmdshell if they can maintain control over its access but I need to present a safe solution to them.  I think I might revise my question title to try and make things clearer.  Sam.

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron Bertrand pointed out, the problem is xp_cmdshell disabled.

There are two options you may consider.

1. Use [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Requires INSERT and ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS permissions
2. Create a SQL Agent job that type is "Operating System(CmdExec)" to run BCP. you may need code to create/update jobs for passing parameters.

Comment: Thanks Eric but I need to perform an Export, not an import.  xp_cmdshell is disabled but if I could find a way to only allow safe use I think the might consider turning it on.
I've read about the SQL Agent technique and it seems a bit too hacky for me personally although I realise a lot of people have employed it successfully.